# Hide "more jobs at Company X" when there really aren't more jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The footer of the job listing page is busy and confusing.  It shows a total of 5 hyperlinks with one making the hyperlink a button:

[image]

This specific company, **kCura** advertises a job listing for an engineer.  At the bottom of the page and towards the middle of the page are links littered with **more jobs at kCura**...Clicking the link yields just this job.

This link should not be displayed as there are **no more jobs** at kCura, this is their only job listing.  This will help cleanup a lot of these things.

I also think the **<< search results** should be placed at the most bottom of the page as to not interfer with what appears to be a pager you guys are using to page the dataset (**<< Big Data Engineer at Jet.com** and **Agile Project...atWeMove.EU >>**)

Sample mockup of how this could look to make it more intuitive:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but you are expecting moral behaviour from a recruiter?

Comment: @MartinJames - Im not sure I follow...

Comment: @MartinJames - This has nothing to do with the company and everything to do with how the page is rendered or displayed.

Comment: Orite, my bad.  Have an upboat:)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the request Jon. I've implemented the first suggestion of not showing the link when there are no more jobs.

I don't see the value of moving the search results link; it's part of the same grouping with the next and previous search results and it doesn't seem to make sense to split them up.

Comment: At least put "search results" in the middle so that "previous" can have the far-left spot.  (This is how TVTropes index pagination works: links to the previous and next tropes and a centered link going to the index page listing all tropes in the index.)

Comment: I really wouldn't keep search results where it is, its a pager with a previous and a next...its almost like you have a previous previous then a next.  Do as you please but it would seem that search results should be on its own.

Comment: @JonH Prev | Up | Next is a pretty common pattern. I don't see anything wrong with applying it here.